# How to import a module in Python which is already imported in another file?

Tags: python, pyqt

In my gui.py module I have:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
        ...
```

How do I correctly import everything from that module in my main.py without `from gui import *` Should I again use in my `from PyQt5 import QtCore ...` or `from gui import QtCore ...`?

Comment: You should treat every python module as independent, each one with its requiring imports to have it working. Python does then smart stuff to cache modules and avoid compiling them twice. So short answer  include the PyQt import in all the modules that use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't import stuff from a module which itself has only imported it:

```
# gui.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def some_function():
    pass
```

you should then do:

```
# main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from gui import some_function
```

The only exception are `__init__.py` files that aggregate modules from its submodules for convenience reasons:

```
# some_module/__init__.py
from .submodule import some_function
from .other_submodule import some_other_function
```

and then

```
# main.py
from .some_module import some_function, some_other_function
```

Since the're not modules that are provided by `gui` you should just import them directly from `PyQt5`.

Comment: I have other classes in gui module too.

Comment: Those you need to import from `gui`. But don't import classes from other modules through `gui`.